# Run Home Assistant via Docker on an M2 Mac Mini

Tags: mac, docker

I understand the concept of Docker. However, I have been unsuccessful in getting Home Assistant to run in Docker from my Mac Mini (which has an M2 chip). Currently, I have the following:

**Dockerfile**

```
# Start the home assistant base image
FROM homeassistant/home-assistant

# Open a port to 
EXPOSE 3001
```

I then run `docker build --tag home-assistant .`. This approach successfully creates an image named "home-assistant". When I attempt to run the image, I'm prompted to enter a port number, so I choose "0". I'm told the container successfully starts. However, when I visit the url provided in Docker Desktop, I just see a web page that says: "This page isn't working"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I’m confused. Why are you building a new Docker image? You should just use the existing one unless you want to add something. (In fact, for Home Assistant to fully work, you need host networking. This will not be possible on macOS.)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use port zero, try something like 12345

> The port numbers in the range from 0 to 1023 (0 to 210 − 1) are the well-known ports or system ports.[3] They are used by system processes that provide widely used types of network services. On Unix-like operating systems, a process must execute with superuser privileges to be able to bind a network socket to an IP address using one of the well-known ports.

See this wikipedia article for details

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers

Comment: "This page isn't working" still appears. Thank you for your response though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I tried and it worked

- Create this file `Makefile`

```
.PHONY: run test

run:
    docker run --rm -d \
        --name=homeassistant \
        -h homeassistant \
        -e PUID=1001 \
        -e PGID=1001 \
        -e TZ=America/New_York \
        -p 8123:8123 \
        -v homeassistant:/config \
        homeassistant/home-assistant:stable

test:
    curl -sI http://0.0.0.0:8123/onboarding.html | grep Server
```

- Run the docker image

```
make run
```

- Check if the server is running

```
curl -sI http://0.0.0.0:8123/onboarding.html | grep Server
Server: Python/3.11 aiohttp/3.8.4
```

- Open the UI in the browser

http://0.0.0.0:8123/onboarding.html

[image]